# 21v solar panel safety issues, and how to get a consistent 12v from it

Tags: solar-cell

We just bought a 50w 12v solar panel but it's actually getting 21v in full sun. Are there any safety issues we should take into consideration with this getting producing almost double what it's supposed to produce? And how can we get a consistent 12v from it?

Apologies for the newbie questions, I bought this for my 10 year old who likes to make electronics projects, so clearly there's a safety issue high in my mind and I'm far from an electronics expert, I just facilitate him with maker type projects as much as I can.

Here's the unit we bought.
https://www.banggood.com/50W-125V-Portable-Solar-Panel-Dual-USB-For-Car-RV-Battery-Charge-p-1506635.html

Thanks in advance.

Comment: is that open circuit, or loaded with  load? What is it when loaded with a (say) 55W 12v auto headlight?

Comment: @Neil_UK no load, open circuit (just the clips to a multimeter).

Comment: Solar panels always output higher than rated voltage when unloaded. The moment you start drawing current from it the voltage will drop.

Comment: @Hearth Thanks. Are there any safety issues with this? I'm not sure what the amperage is.

Comment: The voltage is  normal. 21 V will typically not give you a shock. It looks like that panel has a built-in DC-DC converter to reduce the voltage to 5V for the USB output. Usually stuff on bangood does not come with instructions, manuals, certifications from safety agencies, etc. So it is cross your fingers and hope for the best.

Comment: "50W 12V" implies 4.16A. Electrically it is too low of a voltage to shock anyone, so in that sense it is safe. If experimenting with electronics, 50W is a significant amount of power however. For instance, if a 10W resistor were connected to it (a 50W source) and the panel placed in full sun, the resistor could overheat and possibly burn someone or even catch fire. So I'd say "safe" but under "adult supervision."

Comment: This product is specially designed for outdoor 12V applications, such as car, camping, ship, motor and other motor rechargeable batteries, and maintain sufficient capacity to protect battery power supply.

Comment: @rdtsc your 10w resistor comment, is that cause the resistor is only 10w and not rated high enough? Sorry, very much a newbie in some ways.

Comment: _""is that cause the resistor is only 10w and not rated high enough?"_ - yes, but a 50W resistor could also get hot enough to burn you at 50W https://nz.mouser.com/datasheet/2/427/rhnh-974523.pdf

Comment: Where, roughly, do Zebras come from? Inquiring minds want to know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The panel is "safe enough" when used with normal precautions you should use with any battery powered experiments or equipment.

- The 5V USB outputs will allow charging and operation of 5V equipment.
- The "12V" (18V / 21V see below) output will allow charging of 12V lead acid batteries (car / motorcycle / alarm) and operation of 12V equipment that is tolerant of up to about 18V when loaded and somewhat more under light loads.
- Use of a 12V battery (such as an old car battery) will allow the 12V output to be at about 12V when experimenting.
- The 12V output should provide ABOUT 2.75A at 18V in full sun. It will provide maybe 3A when loaded to 12V or below in full sun.
- ANY energy supply system has some risks. s long as these are understood and allowed for they become part of learning. At 50 W and 18V (see below) the output COULD cause a fire (it may take some effort).
- Shock is unlikely
- Do not put wires in mouth or stand in metal bucket of salt water with one lead attached to bucket and holding other lead !!! :-) .

  - I say that to make the point that it is very safe usually BUT that if you tried the bucket experiment you'd strongly notice the result.
  - You'd regret putting both wires in your mouth! - but you'd about equally regret it if a car battery was the energy source. ].

---

Your PV panel consists of 35 PV cells in series (5 columns of 7 cells) - see image below.
These will produce ABOUT 0.5V/cell in full sunlight when loaded or 35 x 0.5 = 17.5V - say around 18V when fully loaded.

Optimally loaded for maximum power values in full sunlight under optimum loading are said to be at the "maximum power" point and suffixed mp.

So here Vmp = 18V.

You are seeing 21V O/C (open circuit) so Vmp/Voc = 18/21 ~= 85%.
This is consistent with what would be expected.

A "12V"panel is typically about 18Vmp loaded so that it can fully charge a 12V lead acid battery (about 14,4 V) plus a diode drop (about 1V at full current) + wiring and connection losses.

At 50 Watt (Wmp) the current (Imp) will be I = VW/V  Wmp/Vmp = 50/18 = 2.78 A.
This is under full sun conditions at noon with the panel optimally aligned to the sun (point panel at sun and angle panel to maximise shadow length)

The 5V outputs are very hopefully provided via a DC-DC converter so should be capable of currents up to 10A total. However, they may have cut corners and provided a less capable converter. Experimenting will tell. This SHOULD charge cellphones and similar with ease BUT I'd be wary of committing an expensive device to the mercy of a panel of unknown provenance and quality - if the 5V output voltage rose to 12V, or 18V, or 21V a connected cellphone or other device would quite probably be destroyed. If using for 5V charging I'd consider the use of an external  charger that I was confident was trustable.

[image]